# IIS start remote commands - PsServices | PsExec

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net, process, pstools

I have developed a ASP.NET C# web page which connects to remote conmputer command prompt using PSSERVICES.exe and executes some commands against servers.
The execution works fine until I deployed the application on IIS 7.5. The application is supposed to run the commandsn get the output and display to the user.
After deployement, the command execution has a strange behaviour since the command never finishes, it seems that the application enters in an infinite loop and the result of the command never returns.

string output = "";
            string error="";
            string filePath = @"C:\" + area.Name + "*" + area.Server.Name + "*" + action + ".txt";
            UpdateXML_History update_History = new UpdateXML_History();

```
        Process p;
        p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        //Do not receive an event when the process exits.

        p.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        /* Init Structure */

        CommandsLog _commandlog = new CommandsLog();
        _commandlog.StartDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        _commandlog.Command = action + " service " + service;
        _commandlog.Status = CommandStatus.NOTSTARTED;
        _commandlog.Output = "";            

        /*****************/


        //The "/C" Tells Windows to Run The Command then Terminate 

        ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
        PSI.FileName = @"psService.exe";
        PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
        PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
        PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
        PSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        PSI.Arguments = @"\\" + area.Server.Name + " -u " + DomainUser.userDomain + "\\" + DomainUser.userName + " -p " + DomainUser.password + " " + action + @" """ + service + " " + area.Name + @"""";
        p.StartInfo = PSI;
        p.Start();
        _commandlog.Status = CommandStatus.RUNNING;

        output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString();

        p.WaitForExit();


        if (p.HasExited)
        {

        }
        p.Close();
        _commandlog.Status = CommandStatus.COMPLETE;
        _commandlog.Output = output + "      " + error;
        _commandlog.EndDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Update xml file 
        update_History.UpdateXML(area, _commandlog);

        return output + "      " + error;
```

In debug mode, the execution is stuck into this method. When it reaches p.WaitForExit(); it goes back to the code and executes the command infinitly.

This method is called from a webApi controller called CommandController :

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        public Task<string> runCommand(CommandParamsViewModel commandParams)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return ServicePsServicesUtil.LaunchService(...);
            });
        }
```

I have switched to Task instead of simple string but they both don't work. I don't know if there is a way to let IIS 7.5 exucute remote commands using PsExec or PsService? Please, I need your help. Thank you !

Comment: Any final solution about it?

Comment: What's CommandsLog ?